# Insert Missing Dates from a query

Tags: sql-server-2008

How can i insert missing dates from a query i created.  The result below:

```
Date          Frequency
2014-05-18    5
2014-05-20    7
2014-05-25    7
2014-05-27    6
```

I want the result to have missing dates with 0 value as shown below:

```
Date          Frequency
2014-05-18    5
2014-05-19    0
2014-05-20    7
2014-05-21    0
2014-05-22    0
2014-05-23    0
2014-05-24    0
2014-05-25    7
2014-05-26    0
2014-05-27    6
```

Please note that I have read only access to the server.

Comment: are you using any query to fetch the result? or do you have a date range defined. can you add your query or table

Comment: Use a calendar table, select from that and then join to your frequencies by date http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22776.t-sql-calendar-table.aspx

Comment: I am using query to fetch the result from the main table.

Comment: If you have **read only** access, then you are not supposed to insert or update the database. Instead ask your DBA team to help you out.

Comment: @Kin I think the question means they want to insert rows into the result set, rather than insert rows into an actual database table.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is an example using a calendar table (which you really should have). This example just populates 2014 but you can stuff it with as many years as you like...

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Calendar(d DATE PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT dbo.Calendar(d) SELECT TOP (365)
 DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number)-1, '20140101')
 FROM [master].dbo.spt_values
 WHERE [type] = N'P' ORDER BY number;
```

Now the query is simple:

```
DECLARE @s DATE = '20140518', @e DATE = '20140527';

SELECT c.d, Frequency = COALESCE(s.Frequency,0)
  FROM dbo.Calendar AS c
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.splunge AS s
  ON c.d = s.[date]
  WHERE c.d >= @s
    AND c.d < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @e);
```

[db<>fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=675d399cf31869c207bb0abb84c61278)

If you can't create a calendar table (and don't have a numbers table handy either), then you can just put it inline:

```
DECLARE @s DATE = '20140518', @e DATE = '20140527';

SELECT c.d, Frequency = COALESCE(s.Frequency,0)
  FROM 
(
   SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @s, @e)+1)
 DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number)-1, @s)
 FROM [master].dbo.spt_values
 WHERE [type] = N'P' ORDER BY number
) AS c(d)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.splunge2 AS s
  ON c.d = s.[date]
  WHERE c.d >= @s
    AND c.d < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @e);
```

[db<>fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=25401440c95a70537fba5e8ec20ed5fc)

For more on generating sets (of dates, numbers, etc.) see this series:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 1](http://sqlperformance.com/generate-a-set-1)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 2](http://sqlperformance.com/generate-a-set-2)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 3](http://sqlperformance.com/generate-a-set-3)

And more on calendar tables:

- [Creating a date dimension or calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)
- [Using a Calendar Table - Part 1](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6844/sql-server-calendar-table-example/)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(Dt Date,Frequency int)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('2014-05-18',5),('2014-05-20',7),('2014-05-25',7),('2014-05-27',6)



DECLARE @startDate DATE, @endDate DATE
SELECT @startDate = '2014-05-18', @endDate = '2014-05-27' --yyyy-mm-dd
;WITH Calender AS (
    SELECT @startDate AS CalanderDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(day,1,CalanderDate) FROM Calender
    WHERE DATEADD(day,1,CalanderDate) <= @endDate
)
INSERT INTO @t SELECT
    Dt = CalanderDate,Frequency = 0

FROM Calender c
LEFT JOIN @t t 
ON t.Dt = c.CalanderDate
WHERE t.dt IS NULL
option (maxrecursion 0)

SELECT * FROM @t ORDER BY dt
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/21155)

```
2014-05-18  5
2014-05-19  0
2014-05-20  7
2014-05-21  0
2014-05-22  0
2014-05-23  0
2014-05-24  0
2014-05-25  7
2014-05-26  0
2014-05-27  6
```

Comment: The recursive CTE approach gets exponentially more expensive as the date range gets wider. There are more efficient ways to derive sets for this purpose.

Comment: @AaronBertrand The range is pretty small here,but any link to alternatives?For my curiosity.

Comment: Yes, *here*, it happens to be a small range. The problem is people learn this approach and then apply it in much larger scales where it becomes a problem. Why use a slow approach just because it is "ok" in this case? See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed the query to return all the dates in the period I wanted.  Without the joins.   Thought I'd share for those wanting to put them in your query.  Just change the 365 to whatever timeframe you are wanting.

```
DECLARE @s DATE = GETDATE()-365, @e DATE = GETDATE();
SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @s, @e)+1)
 DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number)-1, @s)
 FROM [master].dbo.spt_values
 WHERE [type] = N'P' ORDER BY number
```